# PHP: Error message when binding array values tin prepared statement (MySQLi, SELECT)

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I am new to PHP and **MySQLi** and hope someone can help me with this.

I would like to use a prepared statement for a Select query in order to prevent SQL injection - using MySQLi.

**So far I have the below code which returns the following error:**
"`Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object...`".

However, **if I hardcode** the `$IN` params (i.e. a list of integers) and remove the `call_user_func_array` line **then it works as intended**.

**My PHP:**

```
case "fetchContent":
    $content = $_POST["content"];
    $IN = implode(",", array_fill(0, count($content), "?"));

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tID, en FROM TranslationsMain WHERE tID IN($IN) ORDER BY tID");
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), $content);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($arrTranslations = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $translations[] = array("tID" => $arrTranslations["tID"], "content" => $arrTranslations["en"]);
    }
    var_dump($translations);
    break;
```

**Note:**
$IN creates something like the following - e.g. when $content contains 7 items then dumping $IN returns: `string(13) "?,?,?,?,?,?,?"`

**Update - Example for $content:**

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "6"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "7"
}
```

Can someone tell me how to resolve this and maybe also provide an explanation why I am getting this error ?

Many thanks for any help,
Mike

Comment: Whats the value of `$IN`

Comment: @Uchiha: Thanks. I just added a note for this to the post. It looks ok and generates a list with question marks matching the number of items in $content.

Comment: @Uchiha: Update: Just to add here, $IN creates something like the following - e.g. when $content contains 7 items then dumping $IN returns: string(13) "?,?,?,?,?,?,?"

Comment: I now added an example for the input as well - and am wondering if using a foreach loop could somehow fix this.

Comment: What's the return value of `$stmt->execute()`? What's the value of `$stmt->error` (see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php) after the execute?